# ReferenceError: accounts is not defined

Tags: solidity, truffle, accounts, testing

I was using "truffle test" for testing with JS. gives this error.
here is the code of that part.

```
it('transfer success', function(){
    return Eve.deployed().then(function(instance){
        tokenInstance = instance;
        // testing "require" first by sending larger than the senders balance
        return tokenInstance.transfer.call(accounts[1], 9999999999999);
    }).then(assert.fail).catch(function(error){
         assert(error.message.indexOf('revert' >= 0, 'error message must contain revert'));
         return tokenInstance.transfer.call(accounts[1], 250000, { from: accounts[0] });
    }).then(function(success){
        assert.equal(success, true,'returns true');
        return tokenInstance.transfer(accounts[1], 250000, { from: accounts[0] });
    }).then(function(receipt){
        assert.equal(receipt.logs[0].length,1, 'transfer one event');
        assert.equal(receipt.logs[0].event, 'Transfer', 'the "Transfer" event');
        assert.equal(receipt.logs[0].args._from, accounts[0], 'logs the account thr tokens are transferred from');
        assert.equal(receipt.logs[0].args._to, accounts[1], 'logs the account thr token are transferred to');
        assert.equal(receipt.logs[0].args._value,250000, 'logs the transfer amount');
        return tokenInstance.balanceOf(accounts[1]);
    }).then(function(balance){
        assert.equal(balance.toNumber(), 250000,'adds amount to recevers account');
        return tokenInstance.balanceOf(accounts[0]);
    }).then(function(balance){
        assert.equal(balance.toNumber(), (10000000 - 250000),'remaining balance of senders account');
    });
});
```

upon "truffle test" gives the following error.

`ReferenceError: accounts is not defined`

background : creating erc20 token as per standards.
the first 2 tests run successfully
How can i troubleshoot this?

Comment: Can you show the full js file ?

Comment: There is a problem with the definition of 'accounts' which should be defined at the top of your test in the 'contract' function.

Comment: i had done mistake in parenthesis, initialization was correct with `contract("MyContract", function(accounts) { ...});`

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulate it all with:

```
contract("MyContract", function(accounts) {
   ...
});
```

Comment: yep had done that right

Answer (score 0):

How it actually worked for me :

```
contract("owner()", (accounts) => {
it("returns the address of the owner", async () => {
    const greeter = await GreeterContract.deployed();
    const owner = await greeter.owner();
    assert(owner, "the current owner");
});

it("matches the address that originally deployed the contract", async () => {
    const greeter = await GreeterContract.deployed();
    const owner = await greeter.owner();
    const expected = accounts[0];
    assert.equal(owner, expected, "matches address used to deploy contract");
});
```

});

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).